# Stack Overflow Error when trying to create an exponent calculator using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, stack, overflow

I'm trying to make a simple calculator to practice recursion. This is my code and I'm getting a stack overflow error. I don't necessarily care about the code to make this work as I want to figure it out myself, but I'm not sure why I would get a stack over flow error for this.

Declared in my main:

```
int base=3,exponent=4;
```

My exponent method:

```
static int powerN(int base, int n) 
{   
    if ( n == 0 ) return 0;
    return base * powerN (1, n-(n-1));

}
```

Comment: Unless `n` was zero to begin with, `n-(n-1)` will always be 1; you'll never satisfy the base case of `n==0` and just keep calling yourself forever until... Stack Overflow!!  Are you sure you didn't want just `n-1` rather than `n-(n-1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least three bugs I can see. x<sup>0</sup> is one (not zero). You should handle the case of x<sup>1</sup> (which is x). And, when you recurse you want to pass `base` and `n - 1` (as is you are recursing on a power of 1 - which will always be one). Like,

```
static int powerN(int base, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return base;
    }
    return base * powerN(base, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I can see now where my logic was flawed.